# How should Ubuntu be promoted?

Tags: promotion

Sorry for being a bit subjective but how can we persuade other people we know to use Ubuntu...

Comment: This should probably be a community Wiki

Comment: Doesn't this stuff belong better on a LoCo forum than on a Q&A-site?

Comment: @marco Thanks for pointing out.. Made it community wiki.

Comment: I think general ideas about how people can spread Ubuntu is a good idea. Joining your local LoCo group is one way to help though!

Comment: this is a related question http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/860

Answer (score 18):

Use it everyday! That's the most effective way :)

Comment: That doesn't really encourage other people to use it.

Comment: It did where I work. I run Ubuntu on my Work PC, over time colleagues have seen it and asked about it and made the switch. In total four out of the eleven people I have worked with in the last year or so have switched to Ubuntu or Linux Mint. One switched and switched back to Windows 7.

Comment: @Erigami: what makes you say that? I used Ubuntu every day on my work pc for several years and over time more and more colleagues switched from Windows to Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm suggesting this approach because most of the times when you'd tell someone "You should really try this, it's awesome!" they won't because they feel you're pushing something on them. With this approach they'll see you use it and say to themselves "Hey! This guy is using it full time and he's enjoying it. Maybe I'm missing out on something!"

Comment: @LiLo: You've done more than just use Ubuntu - you've told your co-workers that it's better than what they're using. 

When I worked at home, I used Debian every day for two years, but since there wasn't anyone around to see it, it didn't convince anyone else to use it.

Comment: @Erigami: Actually, I pretty much didn't tell them that it's better than what they were using. I was using (K)Ubuntu on my desktop and Windows on the Ferrari laptop, I just used Kubuntu more. And believe me Kubuntu got it's share of thrashing in front of my colleagues just as Windows did.

Comment: Load compiz and they'll switch... :D

Answer (score 9):

I've brought a number of people from Windows to Ubuntu.  There are several points that usually end up being the strongest sells:

1. They want to have me as a technical resource when they have computer problems.  I tell them I will only support them if they run Ubuntu, since I don't really use Windows myself anymore myself.
2. They are suffering with spyware and viruses on Windows and want to escape that, but don't want to shell out for a new computer.  They like the idea that Ubuntu is immune to all this tends to resonate with them.
3. I try to always have a non-technical person like my wife with me, as they can speak more peer-to-peer and reassure them that you don't need to be a computer expert or anything.  They also tend to be able to explain things in a way that newbies can understand, when I'd be giving Too Much Information.

I usually leave all the stuff about the free software ethos as secondary, just frosting for them.  Some people groove to that, but for most people it's not a selling point; if it were, they'd probably have tried out Ubuntu already.

I also don't talk about the free cost of Ubuntu.  That can make them think, "Hmm, must not be any good".  Instead I'll say, "You pay for a support contract - that's how they make money, and they're actually pretty good.  But that's optional, if you don't think you'll need it, you can use it without paying anything, on as many computers as you want."

Comment: I've found that the .04 and .10 releases often catch people's attention. I say that I'm looking forward to a bunch of new features, _that they'll be able to see soon_ and they get interested in my distro.

Answer (score 7):

My advice is restricted, but persistent advocacy: tell your friends (or Facebook "friends") about all the good stuff, but don't be too pushy. Although Ubuntu has many virtues, so does MacOS X, and even Windows has its advantages - not to mention the other Linux distros. Don't forget that when praising your system of choice.

Actions speak louder than words. Show how much can be accomplished in Ubuntu, how elegantly it works. In my experience, showing the obvious advantages really makes an impression: the system is fast and reliable because it doesn't need a virus scanner; it comes with a full-featured word processor preinstalled; it has beautiful desktop-effects only a mouse click away; for the most part it works instantly, without any driver installation.

Two more things are really appealing and ought to be highlighted: the liberty of free software, with all its ethical and legal advantages, and the community of bright and helpful people - ubuntuforums.org, wikis, and now ubuntu.stackexchange.com. Starting with these, you won't persuade everyone, but you may convince some, and those may be the ones who contribute back to Ubuntu in the future.

Answer (score 3):

you can't: it's a matter of honor.
if one believes that he is on top of the time with windows, you can't change their mind. nobody is pride to use a os for free even if he has no money for windows, they will rather use an old cracked XP... So while this also works they have at least the experience to work with the os of the biggest software producer.

that's just my 5 cents.

Answer (score 3):

That is like asking how you should promote your favorite ice cream... there are endless ways....

Answer (score 3):

How I Promote Ubuntu :

1. Using It Myself: People who walk past me are curious and ask "What is that ? Windows ? " . Then I tell them it is "Ubuntu".
2. Bringing ISO's and CDs on-the-go: While some people do know what Ubuntu is ,they may  have in mind that "Nah ,Windows is better " . Offering them a CD or an ISO can let them try out Ubuntu and they may even install it.
3. I'm on a project (by myself) to offer free Ubuntu CDs to all the people who need them. Although CDs are redistributions , it is being shipped free of ANY charges to people (if they are in Malaysia).

Anyways , I'm sure there are a lot more ways we can promote Ubuntu. You can check out this website if you want some Promotional Materials. The [Spread Ubuntu](http://spreadubuntu.neomenlo.org/) website contains a variety materials such as brochures , posters , packaging and more.